# sigarbt when using dequueResuableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sigabrt

Using storyboards and a tableview my app worked fine till I added another ViewController and had a push segue to the new controller. I attached the segue to the accessory in the cell. Now I get the error sigarbt on the line of code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSUnknownKeyException
>   reason: [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   accessoryActionSegueTemplate.

Please ask for more information as I realise I am not always clear from the beginning, I'm trying to work on it.

Answer (score 2):

You have removed an outlet named `accessoryActionSegueTemplate` in one of the classes used in a nib (or storyboard) but you did not disconnect the outlet in IB. During runtime nib loading tries to make the connection using Key-Value Coding which throws because it does not find the key (outlet).

Edit: Sometimes it's not easy to find stuff in huge stoyboards. It can help to search in the source code. To do this right-click on the file in the Project Navigator and choose Open As → Source Code. Storyboards are quite readable XML files. You'll get an idea of where to search in the interface.

Comment: It runs fine if I remove the connection to the next scene. I cant find the outlet for `accessoryActionSegueTemplate` in the IB.

Comment: Well I did a search for it in the xml and I couldn't find it. I didn't remove anything so I don't think that's my problem.